# Why does onkeypress function keeps calling itself?

Tags: javascript

HTML File:

```
<input onkeypress="addAnother(event)" id="item1"/>
```

Javascript file:

```
function addAnother(event)
{
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        var next = document.createElement('input');
        document.body.insertBefore(next);
        next.focus();
        next.onkeypress = addAnother(event);
    }
}
```

Why is it recursively calling itself here? (The input tags are added infinitely).
Sorry I am a novice.

Edit: I want it to wait for me to press 'Enter' before adding another input tag.

Comment: You're calling the function yourself: `next.onkeypress = addAnother(event);`

Comment: and removing that will be your desired result.

Comment: But then I want to add the property to the new input tag. How do I do it?

Comment: `next.onkeypress = addAnother;`. Event handlers must be functions. If you add parentheses you are calling the function and using its returned value, which is `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
Another doubt: What if I want to pass some more parameters?

Comment: Then you can use `next.onkeypress = function(event){ addAnother(param); };`